# Changing derbyDB schema 'on the fly' in java client

Tags: java, schema, derby

I have an embeded derbyDB in my app, and I am currently testing my code.

If I send the following SQL code

```
set current schema  [newSchemaName];
```

from ij then I can set the schema and the response from the DB of

```
show tables;
```

will report only the tables that exist in the newSchemaName previously identified (although this doesn't always seem to work!)

If I do a similar thing from java code and then perform a

```
getCurrentConection.getSchema();
```

The value returned from the above never proposes the newSchemaName passed in the SQL (although if I use a prepared statement it returns the newSchemaName as expected).

Here is some extra background info...

I have the default database name 'derbyTest' and create 3 other schemas.
Admin
S1
S2
to logically separate/hide information from users that they don't need to know about

I need to change schemas during operation (eg: an admin will change schemas if required to view more 'delicate' info).

To do this I created a method for setSchema(String newSchemaName), that creates the schema (if it doesn't already exist) then connects to it.

However after running the code snippet

```
/**
*method to change to a given schema
*@param newSchemaName the new schema to change to
/
public void SetSchema(String newSchemaName){

String sql = newSchemaName.toUpperCase();//make sure the newSchemaName is in upper case.

ResultSet rs;
        try
        {
            rs = this.sendQry("select schemaName from sys.sysschemas where schemaname = '" + sql + "'");//does this schema exist in the DB
        if (rs.next()) 
        {//the schema already exists
                //send some messages to the user about the change of schema
            errLog.setDevError(1, "derbyDB schema" +sql +" already exists ");
            errLog.add(2, "connecting to " + sql);
                //next line create the SQL for changing to the newSchemaName supplied
            this.sendSQL("set current schema " + sql);//connect to the schema
                //log a message to display the current schema in the DB
                //this next log never shows a change to the newSchemaName unless
                //I use a prepared statement in my java code.
            errLog.add(1, "current DB schema is " + getCurrentConection.getSchema();
    }
        else{//the schema does not exist
        //send a message to the user and output log
        errLog.setDevError(1, "derbyDB schema" +sql +" does not exist ");
        //code to send message asking if user wants to create the new schema....
        }

}//end try
        catch{
//catch errors


}
}//end method
```

If I look at the docs http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/ref/rrefsqlj32268.html for setting the schema my SQL is correct, and the code works if I run directly from ij.

I know that there are some differences between ij and the client side (functions such as describe don't work in the client, you need to fart about with meta data instead).

Is it the same case for the set schema statment. Or does this only work from a prepared statement, which I'm about to test.

If so that begs the question of why I can only change the schema from a prepared statement?

Thoughts and comments greatefully accepted.

David

edit:
A prepared statement works for changing the schema. so now it is only the second question that stands. why the difference between a prepared statement and a normal statement... time for google I think?

edit:
I don't know if it would make a difference but I am on a windows platform, using the standard JDK (6), and eclipse indigo running jUnit test inside eclipse. I can also test on Linux(ubuntu) with opendJDK if it may help to troubleshoot.

Comment: so I just found this link: http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/102950.html it explains that a prepared statement is pre-compiled into the DB. Fine, but they are normally prepared for statements that are going to be called multiple times (as they perform better). Again, that is cool. But I don't expect someone to be jumping from schema to schema all the time (although my code may do so!). So the time aspect is probably a moot point!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is.

You can specify the schema explicitly in your table references, as in:

```
SELECT * FROM S1.TABLE_NAME
```

or

```
UPDATE S2.TABLE_NAME SET COL1=VALUE1
```

etc.

Or, if you prefer, you can omit the schema name from your table references, saying merely:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
```

or

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COL1=VALUE1
```

etc., in which case you will need to establish an implicit schema for those statements, either by issuing a SET SCHEMA statement, or by using the existing default schema, which matches your username when you log in.

I think your question about prepared statements versus non-prepared statements has to do with the fact that, if you don't specify an explicit schema, then the default schema name is established when the statement is prepared.

If it were me, and I cared about what schema I was using, I would specify the schema explicitly in all my table references in all my SQL statements, and then I'd be sure which schema I was using when.

Comment: Indeed I am setting my schema explicity. My supplied code snippet is inside a method called changeSchema(String sql). The line this.sendSQL("set current schema " + sql) sends the SQL command to change the schema. However the output of the error log shows that I am still using the original schema, and hence any following actions on this schema (ie inserts) fail as the DB is looking at the wrong schema. If I use a prepared statement however the change is sent through to the DB. I'm going to update my question for clarity.

Comment: further testing is suggesting that sometimes a set schema call is changing the schema and sometimes not. which is very strange. I see this when I am using the debug view in eclipse. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please understand: issuing 'SET SCHEMA' is **not** what I meant by setting the schema explicitly. I meant: qualify all your table names by their schema name. If you are using 'SET SCHEMA', then you must make sure that you are calling that **before** you have prepared your SQL statement. And since Derby keeps prepared statements cached, different connections will be unable to use different schema with this technique.

Comment: @Brayn re 'SET SCHEMA' Ok fair enough. I have in fact modified my code to include a 'shemaName' string in method calls. However in my above code I do call a separate method before I work on a specified schema, it is the sending of the 'set schema' SQL command that doesn't seem to change the schema. Further testin in ij has also suggested to me that this works only 'occasionally'. I test with DataBaseMetaData or Connection.getSchema() calls, and they fail to return a value that reflects the change of the schema after I have sent the SET SCHEMA sql. What further info do you need to troubleshoot?

Comment: Perhaps getCurrentConnection().getSchema() is misbehaving, and is returning a cached schema value which isn't reflecting the schema change from the previous statement?

Comment: I have thought of that, so I added in a private member to store the value, and capture it from here. so now my code can capture this and insert it into ALL queries that select or insert data, with the user only needing to set this value (but I also set the schema in derby also). The question is how to test which part is failing? In my unit test I can run with the debugger, and sometimes the "SET SCHEMA ***" works, and sometimes not! As I now can confirm my schema from my private member (and take action accordingly on errors).Then overload my personal select/update method with an extra variable

Comment: To experiment to see if this has to do with Derby's prepared statement cache, you can disable that cache by setting its size to 0: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefproperstatementcachesize.html